# Google Cloud Composer Web UI cannot be reached but DAGs run successfully

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I have recently encountered my Cloud Composer service to be inaccessible with the error message saying: ***This site can't be reached. 'xx' server IP address could not be found***. Yet, the DAGs are still running successfully.

I have not made any changes to this service and have already checked whether ***airflow.cfg*** has been deleted.

It seems that there are few resources regarding this. I have also tried some recommendations from the resources I found to no avail. Hoping for some help with this.

Comment: I assume that it was working previously. FYI, DAGs uploaded to the Composer environment are also loaded/parsed by the webserver. Therefore, broken, invalid or resource intensive DAGs can can cause webserver crashes, restarts, or complete downtime. Have you uploaded new DAGs that could have caused this?

Comment: Did you started recently to use some antivirus software or has there been any networking change internally? You could gather more information with these two command: `dig YOUR_APP_URL` (without `https://`) or `traceroute -T -p 443 YOUR_APP_URL` (without `https://`). E.g.: `i23h55c877h449c58p-tp.appspot.com`